# How to convert a URI to Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Converting a URI to a dictionary.

How would one go about converting a URI like "aaa/bbb/ccc" to a nested dictionary like...

```
{
'aaa': {
    'bbb': {
        'ccc': {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for recursion. You can use a node reference to point to the current leaf of the outputting dict while iterating through the paths of the URI:

```
node = output = {}
for path in uri.split('/'):
    node[path] = node = {}
```

Given `uri = 'aaa/bbb/ccc'`, `output` would become:

```
{'aaa': {'bbb': {'ccc': {}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution using recursion:

```
s = 'aaa/bbb/ccc'

def get_dict(s):
    s = s.split('/', maxsplit=1)
    if len(s) == 1:
        return {s[0]:{}}
    return {s[:1][0]: get_dict(s[1:][0])}

print(get_dict(s))
```

Prints:

```
{'aaa': {'bbb': {'ccc': {}}}}
```

EDIT (Pretty print using `json`):

```
import json
print(json.dumps(get_dict(s), indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "aaa": {
        "bbb": {
            "ccc": {}
        }
    }
}
```